# React Native image crop picker No suitable image URL loader found for (null)

Tags: react-native, mobile

Have any one use [this lib](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker)?

How to pass the local image in iPhone to this lib? The scenario is to take a picture, then get the URL such as `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9111DF69-8F9B-4142-88DA-520FDF19925F/Documents/D5612F0C-75F3-4376-A9DF-D499429FBA37.jpg` and then pass it to the lib.

Code:

```js
const App = props => {
ImagePicker.openCropper({
    path: props.uri,
    width: 200,
    height: 200
})
    .then(image => {
        console.log("received cropped image", image);
        this.setState({
            image: {
                uri: image.path,
                width: image.width,
                height: image.height,
                mime: image.mime
            },
            images: null
        });
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        Alert.alert(e.message ? e.message : e);
    });
return <Image style={{ width: 300, height: 300, resizeMode: "contain" }} source={image} />;
};
```

but I got this error: `No suitable image URL loader found for (null)`